# How to create a scope with no namespace pollution

Tags: ruby, scope, local-variables

I want to define and use some variables *without affecting the namespace*.

For example, in C/C++/Java:

```
{
    int i = 42;
    ...
}
int i = 52; // different variable
```

In Javascript:

```
(function() {
    var i = 42;
    ...
})();
var i = 52; // different variable
```

`i` is visible only the code within the block or function scope, and no global namespaces have been created.

Is there a way to write the equivalent in Ruby?

Comment: you just make it `i = 42` and it will be local to the block or the function where it is declared. I do not know what you find wrong here.

Comment: @NafaaBoutefer, in these examples, I can control the scope to be a certain set of code: lines x through y. I don't know how to do that in Ruby (or if it is possible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do nearly the same as the javascript version

```
lambda do |;x|
  x = 42
end.call
puts x #=> NameError
```

Note that there is a subtle difference between the above and

```
lambda do
  x = 42
end.call
```

if there is no local variable `x` in the outer scope the two behave the same.  However if there was such a local variable then the second snippet would can access its value and changes would affect the outer scope but the first version cannot do either of these things.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby variables are local by default. You can create other types of variables with various prefixes: `$` for global, `@` for instance, `@@` for class.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 52
def a_function
  puts i
  i = 42
  puts i
end
puts i # this prints 52
# but when you call the function
a_function rescue nil # this will raise an error and catch it with rescue, because a_function cannot access 
           # local variables of the scope where the function is defined
           # which is the main object in this case
           # so a local variable is local to the scope where it was defined but never 
           # be accessible from scopes of other functions


# but this is different if we talk about blocks so if you do this
1.times{ puts i }
# it will print 52
# and a block can also change the value of a local variable
1.times{ i = 60 }
puts i # this prints 60
# functions or methods are not closures in ruby, but blocks, in some sense, are
```

take a look to this [link](https://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby) for a deeper explanation